# Convert from c# to C++/CLI VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I have following codes in C# to get month names.

```
    string[] names = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;
```

When I try to convert by following ways

```
    cli::array MyMnNames= DateTimeFormatInfo::CurrentInfo->MonthNames;

    cli::array^ MyMnNames = DateTimeFormatInfo::CurrentInfo->MonthNames;
```

But in C++/CLI, I cannot convert...any helps or guidances..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Globalization;

int main()
{
    array<String^> ^months = DateTimeFormatInfo::CurrentInfo->MonthNames;
}
```